# How do I check that a descendent class overrides all virtual methods?

Tags: delphi, inheritance, rtti, virtual-functions

#### Context

In DelphiAST there is a base class: `TmwSimplePasPar` that parses Delphi code.
In addition there is a class: `TPasSyntaxTreeBuilder` that is supposed to override every method in its base class.

#### Question

Is there a way to check that a descendent class has overridden every single virtual method in its base class?
It would be nice to be able to put in a assert.

```
TPasSyntaxTreeBuilder.Create;
begin
  Assert(Self.OverridenMethods.Count = (BaseClass.VirtualMethodCount - TObject.VirtualMethodCount)); 
  ....
```

Note that I'm talking about all virtual methods, not just abstract ones (not implementing abstract methods issues a warning).

Comment: Why not just use abstract methods?  That's what they're for.  If there's behaviour in the base class that must always be executed then have the consumer call the base method and have the base method execute an abstract method that must be overridden by the descendent.

Comment: @J I guess there is a third-party involved (DelphiAST?), so Johan has no control over the source of the base class.

Comment: @Nil DelphiAST is on git... I'd be tempted to branch and fix it, personally.  It's a bad pattern.

Comment: Ask or blame the original author of the code who wrote it like 20 years ago.

Comment: @J... then I agree, sounds like abstract methods are the way to achieve OP's goal.

Comment: Why would anyone implement a virtual method if you wanted to be sure it was never executed? Make all the virtuals abstract.

Comment: The whole point of virtual methods is to not have to override them. Why would there be a warning? (except for abstract methods of course...)

Comment: Write tests for the behavior you want. If the tests pass, then a sufficient number of methods have been overridden. (If the tests pass, and _not all_ methods have been overridden, then maybe you didn't really need to override _all_ of them anyway.)

Comment: FWIW: "`TPasSyntaxTreeBuilder` that is supposed to override every method in its base class" -> Why do you think that? There is no need to override every single method in order to create an abstract syntax tree.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look at the VMT slots of the class and compare them again the VMT slots of a base class.

In Spring4D there is this function (in  `Spring.VirtualClass.pas`):

`function IsVirtualMethodOverride(baseClass, classType: TClass; method: Pointer): Boolean;`

I am not posting the entire code here because it works on some internal VMT structure record - take a look at the code yourself.

FWIW: There is a small bug inside that routine that I just found which I will fix asap.

Comment: Did not try myself, but would iterating TRttiType.GetDeclaredMethods and comparing Name and VirtualIndex be a valid approach?

Comment: @UweRaabe No, because by default you only get public and above and often virtual methods are protected

Comment: Stefan Glienke: While you are not wrong that there simply might not be RTTI on all virtual methods, I think that is only part of an answer to the question @UweRaabe asked. If I am not mistaken it is not enough to compare the Name and VirtualIndex. That will be the same even if the descendant class overrides a method, but the VMT entry for that VirtualIndex for each class will point to a different address. Finding differences there - like in your answer - is the key.

Comment: If you look at the source code for `TStream`, it has a couple of runtime checks to see if it's virtual methods have been overriden or not. You can apply a similar technique.